i used href inside the ordered list in html but i am not getting the output in an ordered format
the output i am seeking for
this is how i want my output to be, but i am not getting that output instead for me its like not in that format its look like unformatted list  the output i got
this is what i got
this is what i want
thank you

Your error is in the declarations of the elements in your list. In your <ol></ol>, you are using <il></il>, which isn't the element you are looking for. You must use <li></li> like in the picture of the output you are seeking for to get the correct result.
You can check out this demo https://jsfiddle.net/nopu06hq/13/
